# How to split string in JAVA

Tags: java

I have a long string and I want to split as a rule-based. 
My string is:

```
    [1] (dokuma) deve, öküz, at tüyü, keçi kılı veya koyun yününün sıkıştırılarak sertleştirilmesiyle imal edilen ve giyecek yapımında kullanılan kalın ve kaba kumaş [2] (giyim) kumaştan yapılan yakasız bol ve uzun üstlük [3] (halk ağzı) abla, anne [4] (halk ağzı) dar pantolon üzerine giyilen ceket
```

and I want to show like:

```
[1] (dokuma) deve, öküz, at tüyü, keçi kılı veya koyun yününün sıkıştırılarak sertleştirilmesiyle imal edilen ve giyecek yapımında kullanılan kalın ve kaba kumaş 
[2] (giyim) kumaştan yapılan yakasız bol ve uzun üstlük 
[3] (halk ağzı) abla, anne 
[4] (halk ağzı) dar pantolon üzerine giyilen ceket
```

My code is:

```
String[] strMeaning = meanings.text().split("[");
        for(String key : strMeaning)
        {
            System.out.println(key);
        }
```

and the error that i saw is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 0
[
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.split(Unknown Source)
    at wikipedia.CreateXML.wordMeaning(CreateXML.java:39)
    at wikipedia.CreateXML.prepareData(CreateXML.java:33)
    at wikipedia.Main.main(Main.java:32)
```

I couldn't figure out. How can I split the way I want? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Open square bracket `[` is a special character used to denote the beginning of a [character class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html), you need to escape it:

```
meanings.text().split("\\[");
```

- [More on Special Characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)

Comment: Won't quite produce the required output as the "[" will be grabbed.

Answer (score 3):

[ is a special character in Java Regular Expressions.

Try something like this:

```
String[] temp = text.split("\\[");
```

Comment: Won't quite produce the required output as the "[" will be grabbed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the square bracket as this is a special character in regex, which is what is used to carry out the matching. However, you also need to escape the escape as the backslash in java has special meaning. You end up with

```
    String[] strMeaning = meanings.text().split("\\[");
    for(String key : strMeaning)
    {
        System.out.println("[" + key);
    }
```

I added the extra bit in the `println` as the matching in "[" will remove the bracket.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the following: `String[] strMeaning = meanings.text().split("\s(?=\[)");`.  You don't want to split ON the `[` but rather on the space coming before the next `[`.